# What is the difference between casting to a Long and calling longValue?

Tags: java

Say I have a variable of type `Number`, assigned a value of type `long`. Is there a difference between casting to `Long` and then to `long`, and just calling `longValue()`? In other words, is there any difference between what the following assertions see:

```
Number value = 123L;

assertEquals(123L, (long)(Long)value);
assertEquals(123L, value.longValue());
```

where `assertEquals` is from the `org.junit` package.

I don't know much about java under the hood, bytecode, or the actual implementation of casts and `longValue`-type methods. The only thing I know for sure is that, if the value instead were something other than long, then the cast would throw an exception, whereas the call would convert the value and possibly truncate.

Notes on casts:
I know the `(Long)` cast is necessary, because without it the compiler gives an error. If I just have `assertEquals(123L, (long)value)`, then it says "java: incompatible types: java.lang.Number cannot be converted to long".
The `(long)` cast is necessary for which overload of `assertEquals` is desired. If I just have `assertEquals(123, (Long)value)`, then it says "java: reference to assertEquals is ambiguous\both method assertEquals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object) in org.junit.Assert and method assertEquals(long,long) in org.junit.Assert match".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in your example, since you assign `123L` to `value`.

If the value comes from somewhere else, the major difference would be that the first assertion would fail when the `Number` is not `java.lang.Long`, but some other implementation of the `Number` interface. The second assertion will succeed for any `Number`, including an `Integer`, a `Double`, etc.

There is a difference between the way the value is obtained internally:

- Method [`longValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#longValue()) is a member of `Number` interface, so it's a single virtual call without a cast
- Casting to `Long` requires a type check to ensure that the object is indeed a `Long`, which is the cast that may fail at runtime. Once the cast is done, Java compiler invokes `longValue` method to do the second cast to `long` primitive.

Answer (score 1):

If value is a variable of type `Number` and references an instance of type `Long`, the two statements:

```
(long)(Long)value;
value.longValue();
```

are equivalent.

The unboxing conversion performed when casting a `Long` to `long` is defined in the [Java Language Specification, section 5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8):

> If r is a reference of type Long, then unboxing conversion converts r
>   into r.longValue()